# What is Drupal caching based on?

Tags: caching

What does Drupal use for caching? Is this something like APC or memcache? Where does it store cache files?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. When the question is not specific for a Drupal version, don't add any version tag. Differently, we should add a new version tag each time a new Drupal version is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, it's stored in the database, in a number of tables names `cache_[name_of_bin]`.

There are lots of other options if one wants to configure it differently.

1. [Memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache)
2. [MongoDB](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) A nice feature is that mongo supports replication across multiple databases
3. [APC](http://drupal.org/project/apc)
4. [Varnish](http://drupal.org/project/varnish) Doesn't replace normal caching, but integrates with Varnish so Varnish can invalidate cache when Drupal does
5. [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) Can generate static HTML files from content.

Also see Lullabots [Beginners guide to caching data in drupal 7](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7) (Thanks  Chapabu!).

Comment: Thank you so much for the links, but I didn't totally understand what you mean by database. you mean drupal stores cache files in database?

Comment: Just as a side note, [this](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7) is REALLY useful if you are looking to utilise the core Drupal caching system in your own modules :)

Comment: @Zim3r It stores strings in the database. See [cache_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_set/6). The Drupal 7 version of the code is more generic, but by default it saves the cached data in database tables.

Comment: @Zim3r Drupal doesn't create cache *files*, it creates cache tables in the database.  If you play around with a site for a bit, and then look at the database, you will see a few new tables called *cache_XYZ* - have a look inside these to see how the data is stored :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, So if there isn't much RAM allocated to database it will act slower than APC or Memcache. right?

Comment: I think one of the purposes of caching is to lower database interactions. But isn't it causing more database usage?

Comment: Replacing one, two or more, potentially complex queries with a simple one is still an improvement, and it's the easiest way to get an out-of-the-box solution. D8 could support files well ootb as well. High performance requirements is an reason to use something other than the DB. Speculations as to which is the fastest during different circumstances is a complex topic, and in my experience rarely as easy as it seems, so I'll leave that for another discussion. :)

Answer (score 2):

The basic drupal caching uses serialized data stored in database for caching.

If you want to have a look at the tables `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cache_%';` to get a list of all the tables associated basic drupal caching.

If you want use caching in your module code then have a look at [cache_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_get/7) and [cache_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7) functions.

Drupal also has support for [APC](http://drupal.org/project/apc) and [memcached](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) by using those respective modules.